# Как создать конструктор сайта на yii2?

Tags: yii2, cms, конструктор

Здраствуйте. Стоит задача подготовить проект, типа конструктор сайта. То есть при заполнении определенной формы(различных блоков) в админ панели и ему генерируется сайт на основе заданного шаблона. Может кто то предложить решение с разбором как это писать? Просто я даже не знаю с чего начать.
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Начните с самой формы и логики ее заполнения, валидации.
Потом уже компиляцию хотя бы статичных html файлов для отдачи для заполненных данных.

Либо, как вариант,https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/runtime-routing.md#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2- - т.е. из запроса берем адрес сайта - подставляем параметр и получаем нужные данные.